# Why is my Monte Carlo Integration wrong by a factor of 2?

Tags: r, montecarlo

I am trying to integrate the following function using a Monte Carlo Integration. The interval I want to integrate is `x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)` and `y <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)`.

```
my.f <- function(x, y){
  result = x^2 + sin(x) + exp(cos(y))
  return(result)
}
```

I calculated the integral using the `cubature` package.

```
library(cubature)
library(plotly)

# Rewriting the function, so it can be integrated
cub.function <- function(x){
  result = x[1]^2 + sin(x[1]) + exp(cos(x[2]))
  return(result)
}
cub.integral <- adaptIntegrate(f = cub.function, lowerLimit = c(0,0), upperLimit = c(1,1))
```

The result is 3.134606. But when I use my Monte Carlo Integration Code, see below, my result is about 1.396652. My code is wrong by more than a factor of 2!

What I did:

Since I need a volume to conduct a Monte Carlo Integration, I calculated the function values on the mentioned interval. This will give me an estimation of the maximum and minimum of the function.

```
# My data range
x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
y <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)

# The matrix, where I save the results
my.f.values <- matrix(0, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))

# Calculation of the function values
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  for(j in 1:length(y)){
    my.f.values[i,j] <- my.f(x = x[i], y = y[j])
  }
}

# The maximum and minimum of the function values
max(my.f.values)
min(my.f.values)

# Plotting the surface, but this is not necessary
plot_ly(y = x, x = y, z = my.f.values) %>% add_surface()
```

So, the volume that we need is simply the maximum of the function values, since `1 * 1 * 4.559753` is simply `4.559753`.

```
# Now, the Monte Carlo Integration
# I found the code online and modified it a bit. 

monte = function(x){
  tests = rep(0,x)
  hits = 0
  for(i in 1:x){
    y = c(runif(2, min = 0, max = 1),     # y[1] is y; y[2] is y
    runif(1, min = 0, max = max(my.f.values))) # y[3] is z
    if(y[3] < y[1]**2+sin(y[1])*exp(cos(y[2]))){
      hits = hits + 1
    }
    prop = hits / i
    est = prop * max(my.f.values)
    tests[i] = est
  }
  return(tests)
}
size = 10000
res = monte(size)
plot(res, type = "l")
lines(x = 1:size, y = rep(cub.integral$integral, size), col = "red")
```

So, the result is completely wrong. But if I change the function a bit, suddenly is works.

```
monte = function(x){
  tests = rep(0,x)
  hits = 0
  for(i in 1:x){
    x = runif(1)
    y = runif(1)
    z = runif(1, min = 0, max = max(my.f.values))
    if(z < my.f(x = x, y = y)){
      hits = hits + 1
    }
    prop = hits / i
    est = prop * max(my.f.values)
    tests[i] = est
  }
  return(tests)
}
size = 10000
res = monte(size)
plot(res, type = "l")
lines(x = 1:size, y = rep(cub.integral$integral, size), col = "red")
```

Can somebody explain why the result suddenly changes? To me, both functions seem to do the exact same thing.

Comment: FWIW, you could vectorise out that for-loop and you'd gain a lot of speed.

Comment: .. but that would be in the realm of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your (first) code for `monte`, this line is in error:

```
y[3] < y[1]**2+sin(y[1])*exp(cos(y[2]))
```

Given your definition of `my.f`, it should surely be

```
y[3] < y[1]**2 + sin(y[1]) + exp(cos(y[2]))
```

Or..., given that you shouldn't be repeating yourself unnecessarily:

```
y[3] < my.f(y[1], y[2])
```